# What languages are used to build Unix commands?

Tags: command-line, source, coreutils

Examples of commands I'm referring to are `ls`, `pwd`, and `cd`. Also, how are these built? Do you have an example?

Comment: Is this homework?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's usually plain `C`. The commands `ls` and `pwd` come from the `GNU Coreutils` package in (most?) Linux distributions (and maybe some other systems). You can find the code on [their homepage](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/).

For `coreutils` specifically, you build them with the usual steps: after unpacking the source, issue:

```
./configure --prefix=/some/path
                   # type ./configure --help to get the available options
make
make install       # could require root access depending on the path you used
```

Be carefull - installing base utilities like those over your distribution's copy of them is *a bad idea*. Use whatever package manager your system comes with for that. You can install to a different prefix though (installing somewhere into your home directory is a good idea if you want to experiment).

Note that although [there is a `cd` executable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50058/what-is-the-point-of-the-cd-external-command), the `cd` you'll be using in most circumstances isn't a separate executable. It has to be a shell build-in (otherwise it could not change the shell's current directory - this has to be done by the process itself), so it is written in the same language as the shell (which is often `C` too).

Other examples:

- OpenSolaris [`pwd`](http://cvs.opensolaris.org/source/xref/onnv/onnv-gate/usr/src/cmd/pwd/pwd.c) source.
- FreeBSD [`ls`](http://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/bin/ls/)

You can find many more of these online.

Answer (score 5):

Just to add a bit more to Mat's answer, although Unix implements these as standalone programs, many commands are also implemented within `bash` (to save it having to spawn a new process) see the `bash` man page for more details, or have a look at the [shell-builtin](/questions/tagged/shell-builtin) tag.

`bash` is also written in C

It may be worth noting that these commands do not **have** to be written in C - indeed, several mini linux distribution use [`lua`](http://www.lua.org/) implementations of these and others.

Comment: Well bash, or any other good shell.

Comment: Note also that some commands such as `cd` must be a shell builtin to work effectively.

Comment: You should give an example of a program that's also been implemented in bash and show how.