# How do I modify the script to not print the path while comparing?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, awk, sed

```bsh
cd /tmp
if [[ $(echo "`pwd`" | awk -F '/' '{print $NF}') == "tmp" ]]; then
        echo "YES"
else
        echo "NO"
fi
cd -
```

Yes prints like this:

```
YES
/tmp
```

but I want only

```
YES
```

Comment: I don't see this is a question about sed or awk... You just print the path with `cd -`.

Comment: I thought if ```[[ $(echo "`pwd`" | awk -F '/' '{print $NF}') == "tmp" ]]; then``` was printing the path, but actually `cd -` was printing the it. I could have done 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null. Still the answer's nice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's printing the path is the `cd -` command at the end.  It prints the path so that you can see what working directory you end up in.  This is a special behavior of `cd` when called with the operand `-` (a single dash), in which case it is equivalent to

```
cd "$OLDPWD" && pwd
```

To avoid this, you could use `cd "$OLDPWD"` instead (`OLDPWD` is a special variable that will hold the value of the previous working directory), but notice that if `cd /tmp` *failed* and your code outputs `NO`, then both `cd -` and `cd "$OLDPWD"` may take you to an unexpected directory.

Instead, use

```bsh
(
    cd /tmp
    if [[ $(echo "`pwd`" | awk -F '/' '{print $NF}') == "tmp" ]]; then
        echo YES
    else
        echo NO
    fi
)
```

The first `cd` will not affect the working directory outside of the `(...)` subshell.

Also, your test would be much more safely and efficiently performed with

```
if [[ $PWD == */tmp ]]; then
    echo YES
else
    echo NO
fi
```

The `PWD` variable will contain the pathname of the current working directory, and is often what you want to use instead of the `pwd` command.  The test simply tests whether the pathname of the current working directory ends with the string `/tmp`, which is what your `awk` code appears to want to do as well (but would fail to do if the pathname contains newlines).

If all you want is to check whether it's possible to `cd` into `/tmp`, but to not actually do that, use

```
( if cd /tmp; then echo YES; else echo NO; fi )
```

On systems with an external `cd` utility, like macOS and Solaris, you could use that like so:

```
if /usr/bin/cd /tmp; then
    echo YES
else
    echo NO
fi
```

An external `cd` utility can never actually be used to change the working directory, but it can still be useful in tests like these that determines whether changing into a particular directory *would be possible*. See also [What is the point of the `cd` external command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50058/what-is-the-point-of-the-cd-external-command)

If what you want to do is to test whether `/tmp` exists and is a directory (or a symbolic link to a directory), then the most common way to do that is not with `cd` but with a test like so:

```
if [ -d /tmp ]; then
    echo YES
else
    echo NO
fi
```