# /usr/bin/type vs. bash's built-in type command

Tags: bash, shell, shell-builtin

I was reading an article on various Linux commands that can show location of programs in the search path, including `which`, `type`, and `whereis`. The article says that `type` is a built-in bash command, and when I run `type type` it indeed outputs "type is a shell builtin". However, when I run `which type`, instead of not output anything (which is the behavior in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/446580/why-does-type-which-say-that-which-is-hashed) AskUbuntu post), it outputs "/usr/bin/type". Is this different output of `which` caused by different distros since I uses Fedora instead of Ubuntu? In addition, why would there be a separate program called `/usr/bin/type` on my system, and what is the difference between it and the built-in bash command? In addition, I also noticed that there is a `/usr/bin/cd` program on my system while `cd` is also a built-in bash command. I also know the difference between the bash built-in `time` command and the `/usr/bin/time` program, but it seems that `/usr/bin/type` and built-in type command do almost the same thing on my system.

Comment: Is `/usr/bin/type` a one line shell script that calls the builtin type? It would be very strange for an external `type` command to be able to perfectly mimic a builtin version. For example you can define a function or alias in the shell that the external program would know nothing about. What you have installed on your machine is not only distro specific but also owner specific.

Comment: `which` is an external command, and so it doesn't know about shell things, like builtins, functions, and aliases. It *only* searches `$PATH` for executable files. I don't know why there's a `type` executable, but see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50058/what-is-the-point-of-the-cd-external-command) for why there's an external version of `cd`.

Comment: related: [What is the point of the `cd` external command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/50058/170373)

Comment: do you have `read` too as an external binary?

Comment: Thanks for all the comments! After seeing all the suggestions I took a further look at the files `/usr/bin/type` and `/usr/bin/cd` and found that they are just executable bash scripts that call the built-in `type` and `cd` commands. I indeed also have `read` as an external bash script. Should I add an answer below to address this? I guess this is just specific to Fedora 35 and it may be related to POSIX requirements mentioned in the related `cd` post.

Comment: [About POSIX and `cd` being a program](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/38819/108618).

Answer (score 0):

In Fedora, the bash package provides a file /usr/bin/type

https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/fedora/devel/rawhide/x86_64/b/bash-5.2.21-2.fc40.x86_64.html

And since type is a builtin for bash, it's likely that this /usr/bin/type file is a symlink to bash.

Comment: It's a two-line script that invokes the `type` builtin of /usr/bin/sh. In any case, it cannot behave like the builtin type as it can't know about the aliases or functions you have defined or the executables that you have manually `hash`ed or the builtins you have enabled or disabled. If run from a shell other than `sh`, it will also potentially give you misleading information about what command is builtin.