Linux command vs bash command, is my understanding correct?
this question may be a bit terminological.
As a new Linux learner, I find many tutorials mention Linux/bash commands. To my understanding, commands are just various programs and bash is a shell like zsh, fish etc. on Linux. Shell will interpret user input and call corresponding program.
So Linux commands are things like cd, mkdir, while bash commands are somewhat specific to the shell syntax. For example, if someone would like, he/she could build a shell requiring run cd instead of cd just doing the same thing.
Is my understanding precise?
PS: I think I can understand the concept of terminal/shell/command line, which have stated in many other questions, and I believe this question is different from those.

This may be a duplicate of Are Linux commands included with or part of the shell? (or similar questions).

"if someone would like, he/she could build a shell requiring run cd instead of cd just doing the same thing" ... that's true, but what does that have to do with "bash commands are somewhat specific to the shell syntax"? Are you saying run will be the equivalent of a "bash command"? In that sense, bash calls them keywords or "reserved words", time in particular being a fitting example as you run time some-command to see how much time it takes

Your second paragraph is very clear, well written and accurate.     I don’t understand your third paragraph, or what you are asking.

Related: my answer to "Are they commands or utilities?"

"Linux commands are things like cd, mkdir" - mkdir(1p) is a utility described by POSIX, while cd(1p) is an Intrinsic Utility, described in cd(1p).

All in all your understanding is correct. Shells have various builtins which replicate real programs and which are often also installed as real programms.
One reason to do this is performance. Builtins do not need to fork which make them faster.

while bash commands are somewhat specific to the shell syntax

I wouldn't call them 'specific to the shell syntax'. Builtins are used and behave very much like external commands. In one case it will call an external program and in the other an internal function replicating a program.
Specific to the shell syntax are things like [[ which is more part of the shell syntax and not a builtin. It is especially recognizable with [[ which allows using > and other shell special characters as 'arguments' which would normally, for a builtin or external command, setup a redirection. (Note: in Shell scripts redirections are usually added after the command and its argument but this is not a requirement. The syntax allows them at any point including in between the commands arguments.)
A shell agnostic way to use the real program instead of the builtin is to use the full path e.g. /usr/bin/pwd instead of just pwd. Or depending on the shell to disable the builtin, e.g. for Bash enable -n pwd.
Also useful is the Zsh shell builtin where which is an extended version of which and shows all locations where a command is found, not only the first.
Last but not least you example with cd is an unfortunate choice. While several shell builtins also exist as external programs there are some which do not and cannot. External programs are run separate from the shell and cannot change the shells environment. cd should change the current working directory. If you implement it as external program you would only change the working directory for this external program. It cannot not change the shell running it. So cd and many other builtins have to be shell builtins.

My bad. I have no extra time command installed. Thanks for pointing it out.

Both are very ambiguous and imprecise terms.
Linux is an operating system kernel, that's one monolithic ELF file with a bunch of dynamically loadable modules.
In one way you could say that Linux is a command as your boot loader invokes it to boot your Linux-based operating system.
The Linux kernel comes with a number of commands mostly scripts to help build it and its documentation.
There are a number of other software provided at kernel.org such as the util-linux package which comprises a number of commands some of which are Linux-specific in that they make use of Linux-specific API and won't compile for other operating kernels.
There are other software that are Linux-specific and not affiliated with the Linux development team nor made available at kernel.org, such as systemd, one of many init systems used on Linux-based operating systems.
Then there are a number of operating systems that use Linux as their kernel and supply (distribute) software built for Linux. That's your Debian, OpenSuse, Arch Linux, Ubuntu, etc to which one may want to include things like Android and ChromeOS or the crude operating system in your smart light bulb.
They're also called linux distributions because they distribute Linux and software that goes with it to make up a complete operating system, like BSD, the Berkeley Software Distribution did before them (and still do though BSD has split into different branches since).
Most of the software they distribute is not written by those distributors. The main added value of those distributors is packaging systems (made of software that they produce such apt, dpkg, yum, zypper, pacman...), the building (for those that are not only source-based) and distributing of those packages, the maintenance of those packages in a stable and safe test (for those that are not rolling releases), and to provide a useful and consistent system with a usable user interface which for the non-embedded ones can be adapted to many different use cases.
One difference with BSDs is that a lot of the software in BSD is developed by BSD, not only the kernel. In particular, the C library and core software is made in house, while on Linux-based systems, most of the software is portable software not affiliated with Linux and that can be used on a large number of kernels.
In particular the C library and core software on generic Linux distributions generally comes from the GNU operating system.
Some of those distributors such as Debian are actually available with the same software built for other kernels such as the one of FreeBSD or Illumos or GNU Hurd. And several non-Linux based OSes include software from the GNU project or from freedesktop commonly also available in Linux distributions.
So "Linux command" is quite vague as it could mean

the Linux kernel itself
software shipped with Linux
Linux-specific software
software included in your particular Linux distribution or more generally that has been compiled for the Linux API.
or just code in some language such as shell languages that invoke those.
or even code in a language that is Linux-specific because for instance it hasn't been ported to other kernel APIs such as the shell that comes with busybox.
or even code in any language but that happens to be interpreted on a Linux-based operating system. For instance, say "Hello World"; in perl or break main in gdb could be said to be a Linux command if those perl or gdb are run on a Linux-based operating system.

The term Bash command (bash itself being the shell of the GNU OS and not affiliated in any way with Linux other than Linux is one of many kernels it can be built for) can similarly can mean:

any code in the bash shell language
a bash script executable
a slice of the bash language identified as a command in the (loose) grammar included in the POSIX sh language specification which includes things like simple commands, compound commands (such as a for...do...done loop), function definitions...
a simple command invoked from the bash shell, including builtin ones or the invocation of a bash functions or external utility on the given system.
A bash builtin command only such as cd, set, echo or keyword such as those used in the for...do...done loop.

In practice though, I've found that both terms were generally used to mean code which you'd run from a shell in a GNU/Linux-based operating systems (generally not embedded ones such as Android or busybox-based ones), in a terminal emulator, for the tasks that you'd generally do from there. "bash" mostly because that's often the default user interactive shell. As "bash" is not Linux-specific, "bash command" often removes the Linux connotation to the meaning and could mean any shell code run on any system where bash is available.

I'd say the extent to what the term command is "ambiguous and imprecise" is directly related to where do we set our reference point. If we go by the POSIX standard, the term command has a precise definition. It is "A directive to the shell to perform a particular task." However, what the OP's intent most likely is, is the distinction between a program (or utility as a sub-term) and a built-in utility. Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/703889/367454


To my understanding, commands are just various programs and bash is a shell like zsh, fish etc

Correct. To generalise, anything line-based (terminal-based) tool that interacts with the user can be a shell. It need not be a command line, but usually it is.

Shell will interpret user input and call corresponding program

Yes

Linux commands are things like cd, mkdir…

This is where I believe terminology starts to get hazy. cd is a shell built-in that represents the Linux kernel system call to change the current process' working directory. For interactive command line use it has to be implemented as a shell built-in, but for a festival interface the user experience could be implemented differently. mkdir is a command (not a shell built-in) to tell the Linux kernel to create a directory.

if someone would like, he/she could build a shell requiring run cd instead of cd just doing the same thing

Yes. But in that particular situation the change directory operation would need to be directly executed by your shell process as changes of state in a child process (a command being run) do not affect the parent process (i.e. the shell). This explains the necessary difference between a shell built-in and a normal executable that acts as a command.

I can understand the concept of terminal/shell/command line

The terminal is a software emulation of a (mostly obsolete) physical device that provides a means for you to access and use a shell or other command line tool. A user's shell need not be a command line; it could be a menu-based system or a text file explorer like Midnight Commander (mc)

"anything line-based (terminal-based) tool that interacts with the user can be a shell", wouldn't mean something like bc would also be a shell? That sounds an overly wide definition. Though you did say "can be", which can hide anything...

@ilkkachu Even worse, I once had a user request that emacs be set as his login shell.

@doneal24, I hear it's a fine operating system with a mediocre text editor. I guess it might work as a shell too...

@ilkkachu getent passwd test4 → test4:x:1008:1008:Test 4:/home/test4:/usr/bin/bc works for me. (For a definition of "works" that limits the user to entering maths formulae, that is.)

@ChrisDavies, yes, and I know some users on some systems have /bin/false or /usr/sbin/nologin as their "shells" in passwd. That doesn't mean any of those would be a "shell" in a sense people usually understand. Though I guess the "exposes an operating system's services" part could be stretched to include something like Python's interactive mode, but I don't think too many people in their right mind would call Python a shell either.

@ilkkachu I've seen menu-based "shells" in the wild, hence the wide generalisation in my first sentence
