# Using '/usr/bin/cd' in a cron script fails while 'cd' works

Tags: bash, rhel, cron, path

I have a simple shell script that I am running via `cron`. I am using it to perform a scheduled `git pull` operation (yeah, I know there are probably better methods, but this is another team's repository and I just need to periodically read from it, so I'm opting for a quick and dirty solution).

Anyway, my script does something like this:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/bash

if /usr/bin/cd /opt/repos/other-teams-repo
then
    echo "success!"
else
    echo "fail :("
    exit 1
fi

/usr/bin/pwd

if /usr/bin/git pull
then
    echo "success on the pull"
else
    echo "fail on the pull"
    exit 1
fi
```

From the command line, this works just fine. But when I run it via cron:

```
57 11 * * 1 /opt/myuser/shell/otheruser-repo-git-pull.sh > /opt/log/repo-pull.git.cronlog 2>&1
```

In my cronlog, I get this:

```
success!
/home/myuser
fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /home)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
fail on the pull
```

When I change **/usr/bin/cd** to **cd** and **/usr/bin/pwd** to **pwd** it works just fine.

I'm just curious if anyone has any insight as to why this might be?

Comment: What are you expecting `/usr/bin/cd` to do in this context? See for example [What is the point of the `cd` external command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50058/what-is-the-point-of-the-cd-external-command)

Comment: "From the command line, this works just fine" – *With* `/usr/bin/cd`?

Comment: As a note, when I call the script /opt/myuser/shell/otheruser-repo-git-pull.sh from the command line the script works as expect. When I call the script from cron, it failes. That is until I change /usr/bin/cd to cd.
@steeldriver, I expect cd to change into the directory I pass it, so in the case change into /opt/repos/other-teams-repo. But it appears from your comment that /usr/bin/cd does NOT equal cd, hence the different behavior.

Comment: @Kamil Maciorowski - it did work just fine using /usr/bin/cd! But it is probably because when I called the shell script, I happened to be in /opt/repos/other-teams-repo, so my pwd was where I was trying to change into. Retrying from /home/myuser, it fails from the command line with /usr/bin/cd just like it does in cron. steeldriver's comment led me to the distinction. I did not realize there was a different between /usr/bin/cd and cd. Thanks for the help folks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The working directory is a property of the process, so an external binary like `/usr/bin/cd` can't change the shell's working directory. (It'll just change its own working directory and then exit.) You need the shell's builtin one, which you get when using just `cd`.

Yes, one might sensibly ask "[What is the point of the `cd` external command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/50058/170373)"

With `pwd` vs. `/usr/bin/pwd` there is no such issue, as the external `pwd` inherits the working directory of the shell, so it can print it same as the builtin one (as long as the path doesn't contain symlinks).